# Combine Multiple Data Sources to a Single ASP.NET Repeater?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, data-binding, repeater

I have a repeater like so:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrRooms" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Choose_Room">
  <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnChooseRoom" runat="server"
        CommandName="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString %>" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"
         />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I bind a data source to the repeater like so:

```
   Dim dbRooms As New pbu_housingEntities
        Dim gender As String = Session("gender").ToString
        Dim hall As String = CStr(Session("hall"))
        Dim selectedRooms = (From sh In dbRooms.Rooms _
                             Where sh.gender = gender _
                             Where sh.current_occupancy < sh.max_occupancy _
                             Where sh.is_available = True _
                             Where sh.building_name = hall _
                             Select sh.room1
                             )
        rptrRooms.DataSource = selectedRooms
        rptrRooms.DataBind()
```

Problem is, I also want to show the viewer the available number of spots in the room. But this requires somehow pull in either the current_occupancy / max_occupancy or in performing a calculation (e.g. max_occupancy - current_occupancy = actual_available) and then returning that with the room.

The end result I'm looking for is to return each room in a button control with text that looks like this:
"Room 1 - 2 Open" "Room 8 - 1 Open" and so on

Comment: Have you tried something like Select New With {sh.room1, .actual_available = sh.max_occupancy - sh.current_occupancy}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amit_g's comment above was the key. I needed to put into the select statement actual_available = sh.max_occupancy - sh.current_occupancy. If Amit posts an answer, I'll change the "correct" answer over to Amit to give you the credit for the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks davemackey :) Something like this.

Select New With {sh.room1, .actual_available = sh.max_occupancy - sh.current_occupancy}